# Google Spreedsheets Apps Script - On Cell Focus

Tags: google-apps-script, event-listener

I'm using Apps Script to add additional features into a google spreadsheet. I've created a custom input box which i want to trigger whenever a user focus a cell in a particular range.

Is there anyway to create an even listener that looks at a particular range and if a cell within that range is active/focus it calls a predefined function.

Thanks,
Mikael

Comment: We're much more likely to be able to help you if you take a crack at the problem yourself and [describe what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Check the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for more information on asking the right questions. Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No there is no focus event. Use a custom menu.

Comment: take a look at the documentation for triggers.